# ¿Como establecer seleccion en DropDownList con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una aplicacion Asp.Net Core , y en una vista un DropDownList y quisiera establecer el valor de los items que contiene la lista desplegable desde una funcion JQuery.
Como puedo hacer esto ?

mi codigo HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="control-label">Pais</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Pais", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Seleccione...", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Pais" })
</div>
```

escribi este codigo pero no esta funcionando :

```
function CambiarIndicePais()
{
    $('#Pais').val(0);
}
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, quieres que se cambie el `value` de tu DropDownList en ejecucion desde la vista?

Comment: Quiero escribir una funcion Jquery , que cambie la seleccion del value del DropDownList cuando la ejecute

Comment: No comprendo a que te refieres con *selección del value*, quieres que te cambie, por ejemplo, teniendo un `value="1"` a un `value="0"` del que esta seleccionado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo, quizá te ayude en algo o te dé alguna idea de como hacerlo, en este caso, la función se ejecuta al elegir una opción del primer `DropDownList`

```js
$('#jsSelect').on('change', function() {
  $('#jsSelect2').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="jsSelect">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>

<select id="jsSelect2">
  <option value="1">Otro 1</option>
  <option value="2">Otro 2</option>
  <option value="3">Otro 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si mal no entendi queres setearle el value verdad?

Te dejo un codigo para que lo pruebes 
El jquery clave que necesitas es :

`Id` del `Select` y el `option[value=valor]` asignarle nuevo `attr`

```
$("#target option[value=2]").attr('value', 'SE LE ASIGNO OTRO VALOR AL VALUE');
```

Te dejo un codigo de ejemplo el cual tienes que seleccionar el valor 2 del select y presionar el boton Seleccionar "opcion 2"

```js
// set option by value - select "option 2"
$('#btn').click(function (){
     $('#hola').empty();
// AL DAR CLICK EN BOTON Seleccionar "opcion2" teniento seleccionado la opcion 2 nos imprime el nuevo valor
//le asginamos al atributo value "CAMBIA" 

$("#target option[value=2]").attr('value', 'SE LE ASIGNO OTRO VALUE');
//lo imprimimos en el div HOLA
 $('#hola').append($('#target').val());

     

});

// clear selection
$('#btn_clr').click(function (){
        $('#hola').empty();
});
```

```css
.btn {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="target">
    <option value="1">OPCION 1</option>
    <option value="2">OPCION 2</option>
    <option value="3">OPCION 3</option>
    <option value="4">OPCION 4</option>
    <option value="5">OPCION 5</option>
</select>
<div id="hola">
</div>
<button id="btn" class="btn">Seleccionar "opcion 2"</button>
<button id="btn_clr" class="btn">Limpiar</button>
```